# How to solve $\log_2 (x) = 1000000$ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, I have the equaton $\log_2 x = 1000000$

How do I isolate and solve for x?  What is the inverse of a logarithm?

Comment: Define logarithm, and then it will be clear.

Comment: Actually, you usually define the logarithm as th einverse of some other operation. That operation is then also the inverse of log

Comment: @SimpleArt So, I think of a log as syntatic sugar for 2^? = 1,000,000.

Comment: What was your try?

Comment: Inverse of a logarithm?  Well, as a logarithm is *defined* to be the inverse of an exponent.  $b^? = x \implies \log_b x = ?$ then the inverse of the logarithm is the exponent.  $\log_b ? = x \implies b^x = ?$.  So $log_2 x = 1000000$ means $2^{log_2 x} = x = 2^{1000000}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally

$$\log_b(x) = c$$

is solved though exponentiation in base $b$:

$$b^{\log_b(x)} = b^c$$

Hence

$$x = b^c$$

What you need is the condition: $x > 0$ otherwise the log does not exist.

In your case:

$$\log_2(x) = 1000000$$

$$x = 2^{1,000,000}$$

Comment: Ah...right, since you cannot raise to 2 to be exactly 1,000,000.

Comment: "Ah...right, since you cannot raise to 2 to be exactly 1,000,000"  ... not quite.  Raising 2 to be exactly 1000,000 would be $2^x = 1000000 \iff \log_2 1000000 = x$.  You are asked to do $\log_2 x = 1,000,000 \iff 2^{1000000} = x$.    $\log_b x = k$ is "what power to I raise b to get k" so $\log_2 x = 1000000$ is "what is x when I get it by raising 2 to the 1000000 power".

Answer (score 1):

> $$\log_2(x)= n \Rightarrow 2^n=x $$

$$2^{1,000,000} = x$$

Answer (score 0):

Raise $2$ to the power of each side of the equation:

$\log_2x=1000000\iff$

$2^{\log_2x}=2^{1000000}\iff$

$x=2^{1000000}$

Answer (score 0):

The inverse function of logarithm is the exponential. So the inverse function of $\log_2 x$ is $2^x$, so by your example; $$\log_2x=1000000\ \rightarrow \ x=2^{1000000}$$